# Tab bar not showing on home page after login

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have implemented a firebase login and want to show my home page with a function, my problem is when showing the home page it will not show the tab bar and when showing the tab bar as initial VC it shows blank, but when I set the tab bar controller as initial VC within the settings it will show the tab bar but bypass the login, how can I get my home page to show the tab bar within my function?

[image: Full Storyboard]

[image: display home view with no tab bar]

[image: When using the tab view as inital VC]

```
          @IBAction func LoginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

            // validate feilds still to impliment


                //if all feilds valid do below
                let email = EmailFeild.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                let password = PasswordFeild.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

                // sign in user
                Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
                    if error != nil{
                        // sign in error
                        self.ErrorMsg.text = error!.localizedDescription
                        self.ErrorMsg.alpha = 1
                    }else{
                        // go to home screen
                        self.transitionHome()
                    }
                }
        }

        func transitionHome(){   
            let homeViewController =
            storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboards.homeViewContrl) as? HomeViewController
            view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
            view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

my attempt at setting tab bar as root VC leads to a black screen but when i set it as inital VC and bipass the login the home view shows the tab bar

```
// let tabViewController =
// storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboards.homeNav) as? 
        //MainTabBarController 
        //view.window?.rootViewController = tabViewController
        //view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } 
    }
```

Comment: The problem is what you had for lunch. Try Greggs.

Comment: Your loading the homeController. not the containing tab bar controller which contains the home controller.

Comment: @DaveBrown: Added solution below, please give a try!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `UITabBarController` in between, assign it to `Class` property of your `TabController` in storyboard and set it to root instate of directly using `UIViewController`. Refer below code snippet:

```
let tabViewController =
storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabController") as? TabController
view.window?.rootViewController = tabViewController
view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

It will work as expected!!

Comment: Thank you so much this has been driving me nuts for the past day and a half!

Comment: Welcome!! Happy coding :)